# How to get a list of probabilities after creating a histogram for continuous data (Python)?

Tags: python, statistics, histogram, probability

I have the data set below (*Data*) and I create a histogram using the code below to extract n (number of points in each bin or frequency). Then I calculate the probability of each of the bins by dividing frequency by total number of points to get the respective probability of each bin (*bin_probability*).

Now I want to get the probability for each point in a list. For example say point 1 is in bin 1 therefore, probability is the first value in the array of 0.65; point 2 is in bin 5 so probability is 0.05, etc. **How do I map each point to its respective bin_probability so that I have a list of probabilities for each point (in this case 20 probabilities)?**

```
Data = [4.33, 4.11, 6.33, 5.67, 3.24, 6.74, 24.6, 6.43, 4.122, 9.67, 9.99, 3.44, 5.66, 3.54, 5.34, 6.55, 5.78, 3.56, 1.55, 5.45]

n, bin_edges = np.histogram(Data, bins = 10)
totalcount = np.sum(n)
bin_probability = n / totalcount
print(bin_probability)
>> array([0.65, 0.3 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.05])
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: This seems to be very similar to [Binning in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880624/binning-in-numpy)

Comment: Thanks for the link @kcsquared! However, when I try this suggested answer:     results = np.fmin(np.digitize(Data, n.sort()), totalcount), I get a ValueError. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @kcsquared's link above, a list can be made with the respective bin locations for each point. The variable '*bins_per_point*' includes 20 elements in an array. Each element corresponds to bin the data point is part of. Next the '*probability_perpoint* variable divides each frequency by the total count to get the respective probabilities.

```
bins_per_point = np.fmin(np.digitize(Data, bin_edges), len(bin_edges)-1)
probability_perpoint = [bin_probability[bins_per_point[i]-1] for i in range(len(Data))] 
>> array([0.1 , 0.1 , 0.15, 0.1 , 0.05, 0.15, 0.55, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.2 , 0.2 ,
       0.05, 0.1 , 0.05, 0.1 , 0.15, 0.1 , 0.05, 0.05, 0.1 ])
```

To verify, the sum of unique probabilities is 1.

```
 np.sum(bin_probability) 
>> 1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right; totalcount is the number of data points, not the number of bins. The second argument for np.fmin should be the number of bins `len(bin_edges)-1`. In fact, running this code on the array in your post currently gives an index error for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kcsquared! What would you recommend to fix this? Is it adjusting the 2 last lines as:     bins_per_point = np.fmin(np.digitize(Vs, bin_edges), len(n)-1) & probability_perpoint = bins_per_point / totalcount

Comment: Correction to my comment: The code in your post doesn't give an index_error; this only happens when you try to print `bin_edges[bins_per_point[x]]` for every element x in Data. Your proposed edit does solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks kcsquared! Can you check the answer above as the accepted answer?

Comment: Only the asker (you) can accept an answer; [there's a delay for self-accepting.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I'd recommend editing the code in the answer to your corrected version as well, for future readers.

Comment: What is probability_per_point supposed to output? Is it: 1. The fraction of all points in the same bin as a given point, or 2. The probability of selecting a point out of all the points in a single bin? The output of digitize, bins_per_point, gives bin indexes; bins_per_point / totalcount does not give a probability. Can you give an example output for your given example Data? The current example does not seem to match it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236658/discussion-between-sarah-and-kcsquared).